# Is it impossible to add a subview to my UITableViewCell's contentView and have it equal width to the contentView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder, autolayout

When I drop a `UIView` in my `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView` in my Storyboard, making them have equal widths is not an available option. Why is this? How can I achieve them having the same width?

[image]

The subview will be moving around, so it's not possible to set its size using pinning it to `contentView`'s margins.

Comment: `Hold option for alternates`

Comment: @JustSid That does nothing.

Comment: Just pin the Leading and Trailing space to the container (without margin, hence option key) and set both constants to `0`. Or are you trying to say that that doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

The cells are dynamic and aren't calculated at that time. They are calculated at layoutSubviews Check out this tut for a quick overview.

http://captechconsulting.com/blog/tyler-tillage/ios-8-tutorial-series-auto-sizing-table-cells

If you absolutely must use the equal width option then just hold shift/option while setting up constraints on a UIView in your contentView and set it's top,bottom,right and left to snap to the contentView(container). Then you can add anything as an equal width/height to that view. But this seems unnecessary IMO.

Comment: If I use the snap option, what if I then want to move the view to the left and right but maintain its width? That's why I want the normal width.